# Ngx bootstrap type ahead value text seperation?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

Im using ngx bootstrap to implement type ahead dropdown.

[Ngxbootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/typeahead)

I have created a sample from the document, but i am not able to give value and showing text diffrent.

I have a list like

```js
{ id: 1, name: 'Alabama', value:"1", region: 'South' },
{ id: 2, name: 'Alaska abc', value:"2", region: 'West' },
{ id: 3, name: 'Arizona cdf', value:"3", region: 'West' },
{ id: 4, name: 'Arkansas efg', value:"4", region: 'South' },     
{ id: 5, name: 'Alaska2 hij', value:"5", region: 'West' }
```

When user selects in Drop down it should show the name, but in ng model i need the value like 1, 2 , 3

but using this ngx bootstrap i was not able to separate these two.

I even tried with ngx-template, but at the end in ui it will show the value instead of text

[my example in stackblits](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6dddzn)

Answer (score 1):

use ngx Bootstraps onSelect method to get the object of selected value.
example: https://stackblitz.com/run

```
change in ts :
```

```js
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
    import { TypeaheadMatch } from 'ngx-bootstrap/typeahead/typeahead- 
    match.class';

    @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
    selectedOption;
    groupSelected = {name: 'Alabama', value: 1};
    statesComplex: any[] = [
      { id: 1, name: 'Alabama', value: 1, region: 'South' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Alaska', value: 2, region: 'West' },
      { id: 3, name: 'Arizona', value: 3, region: 'West' },
      { id: 4, name: 'Arkansas', value: 4, region: 'South' },
      { id: 5, name: 'California', value: 5, region: 'West' },
    ];

    onSelect(event: TypeaheadMatch): void {
      this.selectedOption = event.item;
      this.groupSelected.name = event.item.name;
      this.groupSelected.value = event.item.value;
      }
    }
```

change in html:

```html
    <pre class="card card-block card-header mb-3">Model: 
        {{groupSelected.value | json}}</pre>
    <input [(ngModel)]="groupSelected.name"
       [typeahead]="statesComplex"
       typeaheadOptionField="name"
       typeaheadGroupField="region"
       (typeaheadOnSelect)="onSelect($event)"
       class="form-control">
```

Comment: example not valid

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [On-select](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/typeahead#on-select) typeahead option:

```html
    <pre class="card card-block card-header mb-3">Model: {{selectedValue | json}}</pre>
    <pre class="card card-block card-header mb-3">Selected option: {{selectedOption | json}}</pre>
     
    <input [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"
           [typeahead]="states"
           typeaheadOptionField="name"
           (typeaheadOnSelect)="onSelect($event)"
           class="form-control">
```

in your component add:

```js
      onSelect(event: TypeaheadMatch): void {
        this.selectedOption = event.item;
      }
```

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/run)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

**component.ts**

```js
export class AppComponent  {
 public groupSelected: string = "Alabama";
 public item: state = { id: 1, name: 'Alabama', value:"1", region: 'South' };
  public statesComplex: state[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Alabama', value:"1", region: 'South' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Alaska', value:"2", region: 'West' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Arizona', value:"3", region: 'West' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Arkansas', value:"4", region: 'South' },
    { id: 5, name: 'California', value:"5", region: 'West' },
  ];
  public value:any = this.statesComplex[0];

  onSelect(){
    var i = 0;
    while (i < this.statesComplex.length){
      if(this.statesComplex[i].name === this.groupSelected){
        this.item = this.statesComplex[i];
        break;
      }
      i = i+1;
    }
  }
}
export interface state {
  id: Number;
  name: String;
  value: String;
  region: String;
}
```

**component.html**

```html
<pre class="card card-block card-header mb-3">Model: {{item.id}} {{groupSelected | json}}</pre>
<input [(ngModel)]="groupSelected"
       [typeahead]="statesComplex"
       typeaheadOptionField="name"
       typeaheadGroupField="region"
       class="form-control"
       (typeaheadOnSelect)="onSelect()">
```

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6qznap)